# Why can I see the docker container process when I do a "ps aux" on the host?

Tags: docker

From the host:

```
ps aux | grep java

me@my-host:~/elastic-search-group$ ps aux | grep java
smmsp    20473  106  6.3 4664740 257368 ?      Ssl  17:48   0:09 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.4.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start
```

Then exec into the container:

```
docker exec -it 473 /bin/bash
```

And look at the processes:

```
root@473c4548b06f:/usr/share/elasticsearch# ps aux | grep java                                                                                                               
elastic+     1 14.0  6.3 4671936 257372 ?      Ssl  17:48   0:10 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/sh
```

From the host:

```
sudo kill -9 20473
```

ends up killing the docker container.

Now, I may be mistaken, but I thought there was complete process segregation? Is this supposed to bleed out to the host?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The container is isolated from the host, the host is not isolated from the container. So from the host, you can see the files, network connections, network interfaces, processes, etc, that are used inside the container. But from the container, you can only see what's in the container (barring any privilege escalation configured in the run command).

Comment: thanks, that is what I thought. just struck me as odd to see the container process on the host, I guess I thought that the docker engine would have obfuscated it somehow.

Comment: Good answer. I also thought it would act more like a VM, but was surprised to see internal processes show up on the host